# Find user logged php with select from DB

Tags: php, session, joomla, authentication

I'm doing a website with joomla.

I'm doing a page to insert some data to identify the home of the user logged, and I'd like do another page to modify these data if user need, when he want

Now if I don't want touch joomla login module and I think about a solution but I don't know how do.

Here is what I think to do:

1. User login into my site
2. He modifies the data
3. When the data must update in the DB I'd like to do a think like "update data

Set="$blabla" where id is logged"

How can I do this id=user logged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the user ID by running the following code:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$id = $user->get('id');
```

Source: http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object